# Trying to create a parent-child hierarchy in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a data set that is sorted by account key. when coming to certain rows which have NULL as group key, it should add current account key as a parent key for all above rows which have NULL as parentkey. So when coming to the next row with null as group key, you would set the current account key as parent key for all rows above that have parent key like null.

I have tried to copy a dataset below as mark down table but as you see I can't say I succeeded very well, but I hope some of you can help with the t-sql syntax to create a parent-child hierarchy of this

```
| AccountKey | ParentKey | GroupKey | AccountNumber | Cat      | LineName                     | LineId                               |
|------------|-----------|----------|---------------|----------|------------------------------|--------------------------------------|
| 1          | NULL      | 7        | 3040          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 2          | NULL      | 7        | 3041          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 3          | NULL      | 7        | 3081          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 4          | NULL      | 7        | 3082          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 5          | NULL      | 7        | 3083          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 6          | NULL      | 7        | 3085          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 7          | NULL      | 7        | 3086          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 8          | NULL      | 7        | 3087          | Account  | Salg fisk                    | C6BCDFB2-1AAC-4D05-94F1-879CDC615D76 |
| 9          | NULL      | 2        | 3000          | Account  | Salg annet                   | 26AC86B2-0667-463E-B994-11A5C6D519A6 |
| 10         | NULL      | 2        | 3010          | Account  | Salg annet                   | 26AC86B2-0667-463E-B994-11A5C6D519A6 |
| 11         | NULL      | 2        | 3020          | Account  | Salg annet                   | 26AC86B2-0667-463E-B994-11A5C6D519A6 |
| 12         | NULL      | 2        | 3030          | Account  | Salg annet                   | 26AC86B2-0667-463E-B994-11A5C6D519A6 |
| 41         | NULL      | 11       | 3050          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 42         | NULL      | 11       | 3600          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 43         | NULL      | 11       | 3601          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 44         | NULL      | 11       | 3610          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 45         | NULL      | 11       | 3615          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 46         | NULL      | 11       | 3690          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 47         | NULL      | 11       | 3691          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 48         | NULL      | 11       | 3701          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 49         | NULL      | 11       | 3705          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 50         | NULL      | 11       | 3720          | Account  | Andre driftsinntekter        | 65FFB620-AE42-4BE5-A6E7-BF3339AA04DF |
| 67         | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          | SubTotal | Sum inntekter                | NULL                                 |
| 68         | NULL      | 13       | 4120          | Account  | Innkjøp smolt/settefisk/rogn | F9EE1CE4-22C7-400B-BC9D-E2D3214A5113 |
| 69         | NULL      | 10       | 4010          | Account  | Vareforbruk fôr              | 04E63B6D-CA54-423D-8A44-A4ED99861975 |
| 70         | NULL      | 10       | 4901          | Account  | Vareforbruk fôr              | 04E63B6D-CA54-423D-8A44-A4ED99861975 |
| 71         | NULL      | 3        | 4000          | Account  | Andre varekostnader          | DB7FABAB-7ABA-4B9A-9720-1B538D99B3C8 |
| 72         | NULL      | 3        | 4020          | Account  | Andre varekostnader          | DB7FABAB-7ABA-4B9A-9720-1B538D99B3C8 |
| 73         | NULL      | 3        | 4030          | Account  | Andre varekostnader          | DB7FABAB-7ABA-4B9A-9720-1B538D99B3C8 |
| 133        | NULL      | 8        | 4925          | Account  | Beholdningsendring fisk      | A8BA6F19-A792-44A1-AA21-8F79DB24D224 |
| 134        | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          | SubTotal | Sum varekostnader            | NULL                                 |
| 135        | NULL      | 12       | 5000          | Account  | Lønn og sosiale kostnader    | 5C475EDE-3731-4D39-B11A-C8EE72213FF6 |
| 136        | NULL      | 12       | 5001          | Account  | Lønn og sosiale kostnader    | 5C475EDE-3731-4D39-B11A-C8EE72213FF6 |
| 137        | NULL      | 12       | 5005          | Account  | Lønn og sosiale kostnader    | 5C475EDE-3731-4D39-B11A-C8EE72213FF6 |
| 138        | NULL      | 12       | 5009          | Account  | Lønn og sosiale kostnader    | 5C475EDE-3731-4D39-B11A-C8EE72213FF6 |
| 263        | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          | SubTotal | Sum lønnskostnadern          | NULL                                 |
| 462        | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          | SubTotal | RESULTAT ETTER SKATT         | NULL
```

Comment: Not clear on your expected output... Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: SQL Server already has the `hierarchyid` type to store hierarchies and speed up querying

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question you could use:

```
SELECT  Accountkey, ParentKey,GroupKey,AccountNumber, NEW_PARID
FROM (
             SELECT Accountkey, ParentKey,GroupKey,AccountNumber, AccountKey AS NEW_PARID, LAG(ACCOUNTKEY) OVER (ORDER BY Accountkey) AS PREC
             FROM MYT
             WHERE  GroupKey IS NULL 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT A.Accountkey, A.ParentKey,A.GroupKey,A.AccountNumber, B.Accountkey AS NEW_PARID, B.PREC
             FROM MYT A 
             INNER JOIN ( SELECT Accountkey, ParentKey,GroupKey,AccountNumber, AccountKey AS NEW_PARID, LAG(ACCOUNTKEY) OVER (ORDER BY Accountkey) AS PREC
             FROM MYT
             WHERE  GroupKey IS NULL) B ON A.Accountkey < B.Accountkey  AND (B.PREC IS NULL OR B.PREC<A.accountKey)
             WHERE A.GroupKey IS NOT NULL 
             AND B.GroupKey IS NULL
) X ORDER BY ACCOUNTKEY
```

You can write it in this way too (it's the same query):

```
WITH X AS (SELECT Accountkey, ParentKey,GroupKey,AccountNumber, AccountKey AS NEW_PARID, LAG(ACCOUNTKEY) OVER (ORDER BY Accountkey) AS PREC
             FROM MYT
             WHERE  GroupKey IS NULL)
SELECT X.*
FROM X
UNION ALL 
 SELECT A.Accountkey, A.ParentKey,A.GroupKey,A.AccountNumber, X.Accountkey AS NEW_PARID, X.PREC
 FROM MYT A 
 INNER JOIN X  ON A.Accountkey < X.Accountkey  AND (X.PREC IS NULL OR X.PREC<A.accountKey)
 WHERE A.GroupKey IS NOT NULL
```

Output (MYT is the name of the table, the new parentid column is NEW_PARID):

```
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
| Accountkey | ParentKey | GroupKey | AccountNumber | NEW_PARID |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
|          1 | NULL      | 7        | 3040          |        67 |
|          2 | NULL      | 7        | 3041          |        67 |
|          3 | NULL      | 7        | 3081          |        67 |
|          4 | NULL      | 7        | 3082          |        67 |
|          5 | NULL      | 7        | 3083          |        67 |
|          6 | NULL      | 7        | 3085          |        67 |
|          7 | NULL      | 7        | 3086          |        67 |
|          8 | NULL      | 7        | 3087          |        67 |
|          9 | NULL      | 2        | 3000          |        67 |
|         10 | NULL      | 2        | 3010          |        67 |
|         11 | NULL      | 2        | 3020          |        67 |
|         12 | NULL      | 2        | 3030          |        67 |
|         41 | NULL      | 11       | 3050          |        67 |
|         42 | NULL      | 11       | 3600          |        67 |
|         43 | NULL      | 11       | 3601          |        67 |
|         44 | NULL      | 11       | 3610          |        67 |
|         45 | NULL      | 11       | 3615          |        67 |
|         46 | NULL      | 11       | 3690          |        67 |
|         47 | NULL      | 11       | 3691          |        67 |
|         48 | NULL      | 11       | 3701          |        67 |
|         49 | NULL      | 11       | 3705          |        67 |
|         50 | NULL      | 11       | 3720          |        67 |
|         67 | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          |        67 |
|         68 | NULL      | 13       | 4120          |       134 |
|         69 | NULL      | 10       | 4010          |       134 |
|         70 | NULL      | 10       | 4901          |       134 |
|         71 | NULL      | 3        | 4000          |       134 |
|         72 | NULL      | 3        | 4020          |       134 |
|         73 | NULL      | 3        | 4030          |       134 |
|        133 | NULL      | 8        | 4925          |       134 |
|        134 | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          |       134 |
|        135 | NULL      | 12       | 5000          |       263 |
|        136 | NULL      | 12       | 5001          |       263 |
|        137 | NULL      | 12       | 5005          |       263 |
|        138 | NULL      | 12       | 5009          |       263 |
|        263 | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          |       263 |
|        462 | NULL      | NULL     | NULL          |       462 |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

**Updated 20171221 - for MSSQL 2008**
You can try this (but pay attention for performance if you have a large dataset):

```
 SELECT A.ACCOUNTKEY
    , A.PARENTKEY
    , (SELECT MIN(B.ACCOUNTKEY) FROM MYT B WHERE B.GROUPKEY IS NULL AND A.ACCOUNTKEY<=B.ACCOUNTKEY) AS NEW_PARID
FROM MYT A
/* WHERE A.GROUPKEY IS NOT NULL*/
```

Comment: Thanks For CTE :) I was trying with CTE too. A good learning from your answer

Comment: @Prabhat In this case, CTE is just to have (perhaps) a better readble query, but it doesn't add anything else.  Usually I prefer to use CTE when they are almost necessary (true recursive query).

Comment: Thanks for excellent work. This is just what I needed. Thank you again :-)

Comment: Hello again. The  code above works on SQL Server 2012 and later versions. But of course the server that this code will be executed on is SQL Server 2008. How easy and any suggestion to rewrite the t-sql code to run on SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I need to rewrite to work on SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT AccountKey,
       LineName,
       AccountName,
       GroupKey,
       AccountNumber,
       ParentAccountKey
INTO tempAccount
FROM
(
    SELECT AccountKey,
           LineName,
           AccountName,
           GroupKey,
           AccountNumber,
           AccountKey AS ParentAccountKey, 
           LAG(AccountKey) OVER(ORDER BY AccountKey) AS PREC
    FROM tempTable2
    WHERE GroupKey IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.AccountKey,
           A.LineName,
           A.AccountName,
           A.GroupKey,
           A.AccountNumber,
           B.AccountKey AS ParentAccountKey,
           B.PREC
    FROM tempTable2 A
         INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT AccountKey,
               LineName,
               AccountName,
               GroupKey,
               AccountNumber,
               AccountKey AS ParentAccountKey,
               LAG(AccountKey) OVER(ORDER BY AccountKey) AS PREC
        FROM tempTable2
        WHERE GroupKey IS NULL
    ) B ON A.AccountKey < B.AccountKey
           AND (B.PREC IS NULL
                OR B.PREC < A.AccountKey)
    WHERE A.GroupKey IS NOT NULL
          AND B.GroupKey IS NULL
) X
ORDER BY AccountKey;
```

Comment: Please don't put additional information in answer section.